# Does Discipline Focus (Insightful Strikes) add the Wisdom bonus to each attack of Flashing Sun's full-attack action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

Discipline Focus (Insightful Strikes) states the following:

> At 4th level, you can add your Wisdom modifier as a bonus on damage
> rolls whenever you execute a strike from the chosen discipline. At
> 12th level, you can choose a second discipline to which this ability
> applies.

and Flashing Sun states the following:

> Flashing sun allows you to make an additional melee attack during this
> round. As part of this maneuver, you take a full attack action and
> make your normal melee attacks. However, you can make one additional
> attack this round at your highest attack bonus. All the attacks you
> make this round, including the extra attack granted by this maneuver,
> are made with a -2 penalty.

So, the thing is, Flashing Sun includes a full attack in its description, and Insightful Strikes says "damage rolls", in plural. Does this mean that it adds the Wis bonus to each attack's damage roll, only to the one added by the strike itself, or neither?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> you can add your Wisdom modifier as a bonus on damage roll**s** whenever you execute a strike from the chosen discipline.

<sup>(**emphasis** mine)</sup>

Insightful strikes adds your Wisdom modifier as a bonus on damage rolls, plural. As long as you’re executing a strike, any damage rolls you make include that bonus. That means every attack made while initiating *flashing sun* includes that bonus.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes.

Discipline Focus says

> **whenever** you execute a strike from the chosen discipline.

Implying that there is no limit to how many times you may use this.

Flashing Sun says

> at your **highest** attack bonus

I would say yes, you can add your wisdom modifier *unless* your GM says otherwise. In the end it's up to your Dungeon Master.